# When is an HNN-extension finitely presented?

Tags: gr.group-theory, reference-request

Let $G=\langle H, t; K^t=K^{\prime}\rangle$ be an HNN-extension of $H$, with $t$ inducing the isomorphism $\phi: K\rightarrow K^{\prime}$. I was wondering if the following question can be answered, and if so what is the answer,

> When is $G$ finitely presented?

It seems "obvious" that the answer should be "when $H$ is finitely presentable and $K$ is finitely generated". However, Grigorchuk's group is *not* finitely presentable but *does* have a finitely-presentable HNN-extension (Lysenok’s extension).

EDIT: Now, I am not expecting the question to be answerable. What I would really like is an incomplete answer, along the lines of,

> If you put *these* restrictions on $H$ and $K$ (and perhaps on the isomorphism $\phi$) then you can say something.

Comment: Well, as you justify, the answer is not obvious. The problem is non-trivial (and likely has no general answer) even it the most degenerate instance of HNN, namely that of a semidirect product $G=H\rtimes\mathbf{Z}$. This group can be finitely presented even if $H$ is not finitely presented, or even finitely generated. For instance, the Thompson group $F$ of the interval can be written in either of these ways (and also with $H$ finitely presented). Such phenomena also occur in the context of metabelian groups.

Comment: A similar example to the one by Yves is the wreath product $\mathbb{Z}\wr\mathbb{Z}$.


Comment: What sort of answer do you (the OP) hope for from this question?  As you correctly point out, the naive guess is false.  As Yves says, it's unlikely that there is an answer.

Comment: Steve D - $\mathbb{Z}\wr\mathbb{Z}$ is not finitely presented!

Comment: @HW: probably SteveD means that ZwrZ admits a f.p. HNN extension (Baumslag's group).

Comment: Yves - huh, I didn't know that.  Which Baumslag's group?  $\langle a,b\mid a^{(a^b)}=a^2\rangle$?

Steve D - sorry if so!

Comment: @HW: The sort of answer I would hope for would be "If you put *these* restrictions on $G$ and $K$ (and perhaps on the isomorphism between $K$ and $K^{\prime}$) then you can say something." Along the lines of the Baumslag-Tretfoff conditions for residual finiteness; sufficient, but not necessary.

Comment: AL - thanks, that considerably clarifies things.  You might want to edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @HW: there are several Baumslag groups :p... view ZwrZ as the semidirect product $Z[t,t^{-1}]\rtimes \langle t\rangle$. (this is certainly not Baumslag's language, who rather likes group presentations). Consider the injective homomorphism of the free abelian group of infinite rank $Z[t,t^{-1}]$ given by multiplication by $(t-1)$. The associated ascending HNN-extension is thus the semidirect product $Z[t,t^{-1},(t-1)^{-1}]\rtimes \langle t,t-1\rangle$, where $\langle t,t-1\rangle$ is isomorphic to $Z^2$. Baumslag proved it's f.p., with a more conceptual and general proof by Bieri-Strebel.

Comment: @HW: I forgot to say: the above endomorphism of $Z[t,t^{-1}]$ is first extended to the semidirect product, acting trivially on $t$. This gives an injective endomorphism of ZwrZ, out of which the ascending HNN extension is made.

Comment: Yves - many thanks!  That's very interesting.  (I think the Baumslag's group I mentioned used to be called 'the Baumslag--Gersten group'.  Somehow Gersten got forgotten.)

Comment: AL - thanks for the edit.  I think you mean 'If you put these restrictions on $H$ and $K$...', don't you?

Comment: Finite L-presentations let you get finitely presented HNN extensions in many cases. 

Comment: @Henry: This is a group constructed by Baumslag and Remeslennikov (independently). In fact they had a more general construction (with $t-1$ replaced by any monic polynomial with at least two monomials). The Baumslag-Gersten group is $\langle a,b\mid a^{a^b}=a^2\rangle$. It was also constructed by Baumslag, and Gersten had no role in it. He did use it and proved some properties of it. 


Comment: For ascending HNN extensions, i.e. $H=K$ (as in Baumslag-Remeslennikov case, in the Grigorchuk case, and many others) one needs, as Ben Steinberg ponted out that $H$ has a finite L-presentation with respect to the endomorphism $\phi:H\to K'$. That is there are finite number of relations $r_1=1,...,r_k=1$ so that the set of relations $\\{\phi^m(r_j)=1\mid m\ge 0, 1\le j\le k\\}$ defines $H$. 

Comment: More examples can be found in Sapir, Mark, Wise, Daniel T.,
Ascending HNN extensions of residually finite groups can be non-Hopfian and can have very few finite quotients.
J. Pure Appl. Algebra 166 (2002), no. 1-2, 191–202 and in Olʹshanskii, Alexander Yu.; Sapir, Mark V. Non-amenable finitely presented torsion-by-cyclic groups. Publ. Math. Inst. Hautes Études Sci. No. 96 (2002), 43–169.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting comments, Mark.  Perhaps either you or Benjamin could write an answer about L-presentations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are my  comments combined into an answer.

For ascending HNN extensions, i.e. $H=K$, $\phi\colon H\to K'$ an injective endomorphism (as in Baumslag-Remeslennikov case (see above), in the Grigorchuk case, and many others) one needs, as Ben Steinberg ponted out that $H$ has a finite L-presentation (named after Igor Lysenok, who proved that the Grigorchuk group $G_1$ has such a presentation) with respect to the endomorphism $\phi:H\to K′$. That is there are finite number of relations $r_1=1,...,r_k=1$ so that the set of relations $\{\phi^m(r_j)=1\mid m\ge 0,1\le j\le k\}$ defines $H$. Here we consider $\phi$ as a substitution $x\mapsto u_x$ where $u_x$ is any word representing $\phi(x)$ in $H$, $x$ a generator of $H$. Indeed, in this case $G$ (generated by the finite generating set $X$ of $H$ and the free letter $t$) has finite presentation consisting of relations $r_1,...,r_k$ and the HNN relations $x^t=\phi(x), x\in X$. I think that the converse statement should also be true: if the HNN extension is finitely presented then $H$ has a finite L-presentation with respect to $\phi$.

More examples can be found in Sapir, Mark, Wise, Daniel T., Ascending HNN extensions of residually finite groups can be non-Hopfian and can have very few finite quotients. J. Pure Appl. Algebra 166 (2002), no. 1-2, 191–202 and in Olʹshanskii, Alexander Yu.; Sapir, Mark V. Non-amenable finitely presented torsion-by-cyclic groups. Publ. Math. Inst. Hautes Études Sci. No. 96 (2002), 43–169. In both cases it was crucial that the "extended" group $H$ has an L-presentation, in fact it was constructed as such.

For arbitrary HNN extensions the situation is more difficult but not hopeless, I think that necessary and sufficient conditions can be found in many more cases.

Comment: You might give some link where to learn about L-presentations (or even define it, if it's short), I'm not sure it's very standard knowledge.

Comment: I defined it in my answer, after the words "That is". The term was, I think, invented by Bartholdi, http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0007062

Comment: I doubt about your characterization, as I think you assume that the kernel of the homomorphism to $\mathbf{Z}$ is finitely generated (you don't really say which generators you take in an L-presentation but in Bartholdi's paper it's assumed to be finite). But there are ascending HNN extensions of infinitely generated groups (e.g. Thompson's group or Baumslag's group) that are finitely presented.

Comment: The kernel is never finitely generated if $\phi$ is not onto because it is an infinite increasing union of isomorphic groups. I assume for simplicity that $H$ is finitely generated i.e. $X$ is finite. If $X$ is infinite, one needs to assume, in addition, that $X$ is a union of a finite number of $\phi$-orbits (or something similar).  

Comment: Sorry, I meant: you assume that $H$ is finitely generated (as you have guessed!).

Comment: Most probably the correct formulation for infinite $X$ is this: $H$ has a finite $L$-presentation if there exists a finite subset $X_0\subseteq X$ and a finite set of relations $r_1,...,r_k$ of $H$, each $r_i$ a word in $X_0$ such that $H$ is generated by $\cup _{n\ge 0}\phi^n(X)$ and is presented by the set of relations $\phi^n(r_j)$, $n\ge 0, 1\le j\le k$. 

Comment: In that case the HNN extension $G$ is generated by $X_0\cup \phi(X_0)\cup \{t\}$ and given by the relations $r_1,...,r_k$ and the HNN relations $x^t_j=\phi(x_j), j=1,...,k$. I did not check it, though.

Comment: The earliest use of the term ``L-presentation'' that I have seen is in Grigorchuk's paper ``On the system of defining relations and the Schur multiplier of periodic groups generated by finite automata'' in Groups St. Andrews 1997 in Bath, I (page 293) http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1676626