# A group, all of whose non-trivial mapping tori are finitely presentable?

Tags: gr.group-theory

By a mapping tori of $G$, I mean a semidirect product $G\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$, and by a trivial mapping tori I mean one isomorphic to $G\times\mathbb{Z}$.

If $G$ is finitely generated but not finitely presentable, clearly $G\times\mathbb{Z}$ is not finitely presentable. My question is: Does there exist a group $G$, with some property so as to be interesting, and where every other mapping torus is finitely presentable?

More precisely: Does there exist a finitely generated, non-finitely presentable group $G$ such that:

1. $\operatorname{Out}(G)$ is not virtually cyclic, and
2. for all $\phi\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)\setminus\operatorname{Inn}(G)$, the mapping torus $G\rtimes_{\phi}\mathbb{Z}$ is finitely presentable?

Condition (1) ensures that any answer isn't just a case of checking finitely many outer automorphisms (and there are examples with $\operatorname{Out}(G)$ finite and with $\operatorname{Out}(G)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, via Bumagin and Wise's version of Rips' construction). Note that $\operatorname{Out}(G)$ is considered rather than $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, as two automorphisms of $G$ from the same outer automorphism class define isomorphic mapping tori.

---

My motivation here is that I was idly wondering if a group/class of groups I was looking at has this property. However, I do not know if *any* groups have this property, so this question is a sanity check (and seems interesting in it's own right). Moreover, I am interested to see what techniques could be used here - so multiple answers using a variety of techniques would be amazing!

Comment: What happens for the lamplighter group? Does it have *any* finitely presented mapping torus?

Comment: You might look at the comments to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104400/when-is-an-hnn-extension-finitely-presented

Comment: As a toy model one can ask the same question about nontrivial mapping tori which are all finitely generated. Does it imply finite generation of the original group?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda No, it doesn't have any.

Comment: The non-fp group $\mathbf{Z}\ltimes (\mathbf{Z}[1/2]^2)$, action by diagonal $(2,2^{-1})$ might be more interesting to look at. Of course one can cheat and act by a virtually inner automorphism (e.g., flip of components). But otherwise any "non-inner enough" automorphism is likely to produce a fp group.

Comment: I'd say another "candidate" comes from Thompson's group $F$. Let $\phi:F\to\mathbb{Z}$ send $f$ to the log base 2 of the slope of $f$ at 0 plus the log base 2 of the slope of $f$ at 1. Then the kernel of $\phi$ is finitely generated but not finitely presented. I wouldn't be surprised if all the non-trivial mapping tori of this kernel are isomorphic to $F$, or really close. And $F$ has lots of automorphisms, so if this turned out to work, it would be "interesting".